# What is the meaning of the -L option in SQLplus?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Like in :

```
sqlplus -L $CONFIG_USR/$CONFIG_PWD @${DIR_BIN}/do_plsql_basel2.sql $SCHEMA.${MAPNAME} $FREQUENCY $CONFIG_USR $CONFIG_PWD >$DIR_LOG/${SCRIPTNAME}_$$.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [SQLPLus manpage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch4.htm) :

> Specifies not to reprompt for username or password if the initial connection does not succeed.

Comment: For completeness [here's the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169374)