# sqlplus -L option

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a shell script containing an oracle sqlplus command with -L option as below, I cannot find the meaning of this option anywhere on the internet, could anyone provide me with the meaning and hopefully some documentation ?

```
sqlplus -L ${User}/$Pass@$Alias &>/dev/null
```

Thank you

Comment: heve you tried `sqlplus --help`?

Comment: I believe this means that it only attempts to log in once and then quits instead of prompting for password two more times. I see in documentation that this is `-l` (lowercase) but [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360728/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-l-option-in-sqlplus) suggests capital L is the correct flag. Perhaps in older version it was capital.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the -L option in SQLplus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360728/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-l-option-in-sqlplus)

Comment: *I cannot find the meaning of this option anywhere on the internet*  I do not think so: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/options.html

Comment: @Jens That page has `-l`, not `-L`. But maybe it's case-insensitive.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/starting-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-2BE698CF-8752-4F9C-B0B1-8CFEBF531AB1

Comment: From the output of `sqlplus --help` - "-L     Attempts to log on just once, instead of
reprompting on error."

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, it turns out it is the same as -l which means try logon once, @Jens I did find -l but thought it would be mentioned if it was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says try to log in once, and then give up if that doesn't work.

By default you'll notice if you get a bad connect attempt, you get 3 more. Probably helpful for scripts/automation.

It's -L, -l won't work.

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus --help

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Use SQL*Plus to execute SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements.

Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V

    -H         Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
           usage help.
    -V         Displays the SQL*Plus version.

Usage 2: sqlplus [ [<option>] [{logon | /nolog}] [<start>] ]

  <option> is: [-AC] [-C <version>] [-F] [-L] [-M "<options>"] [-NOLOGINTIME]
           [-R <level>] [-S]

    -AC        Enable Application Continuity.
    -C <version>   Sets the compatibility of affected commands to the
           version specified by <version>.  The version has
           the form "x.y[.z]".  For example, -C 10.2.0
    -F         This option improves performance in general. It changes
           the default values settings.
           See SQL*Plus User's Guide for the detailed settings.
    -L         Attempts to log on just once, instead of
           reprompting on error.
    -M "<options>" Sets automatic HTML or CSV markup of output.  The options
           have the form:
           {HTML html_options|CSV csv_options}
           See SQL*Plus User's Guide for detailed HTML and CSV options.
    -NOLOGINTIME   Don't display Last Successful Login Time.
    -R <level>     Sets restricted mode to disable SQL*Plus commands
           that interact with the file system.  The level can
           be 1, 2 or 3.  The most restrictive is -R 3 which
           disables all user commands interacting with the
           file system.
    -S         Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
           the SQL*Plus banner, prompts, and echoing of
           commands.

  <logon> is: {<username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | / }
          [AS {SYSDBA | SYSOPER | SYSASM | SYSBACKUP | SYSDG
          | SYSKM | SYSRAC}] [EDITION=value]

    Specifies the database account username, password and connect
    identifier for the database connection.  Without a connect
    identifier, SQL*Plus connects to the default database.

    The AS SYSDBA, AS SYSOPER, AS SYSASM, AS SYSBACKUP, AS SYSDG,
    AS SYSKM and AS SYSRAC options are database administration privileges.

    <connect_identifier> can be in the form of Net Service Name
    or Easy Connect.

      @[<net_service_name> | [[//]Host[:Port]/<service_name>] |
    [[[protocol:]//]host1{,host12}[:port1]{,host2:port2}[/service_name]
     [:server][/instance_name][?[parameter_name=value]
     {&parameter_name=value}]]]

    <net_service_name> is a simple name for a service that resolves
    to a connect descriptor.

    Example: Connect to database using Net Service Name and the
         database net service name is ORCL.

       sqlplus myusername/mypassword@ORCL

    Host specifies the host name or IP address of the database
    server computer.

    Port specifies the listening port on the database server.

    <service_name> specifies the service name of the database you
    want to access.

    Example: Connect to database using Easy Connect and the
         Service name is ORCL.

       sqlplus myusername/mypassword@Host/ORCL

    The /NOLOG option starts SQL*Plus without connecting to a
    database.

    The EDITION specifies the value for Session Edition.


  <start> is: @<URL>|<filename>[.<ext>] [<parameter> ...]

    Runs the specified SQL*Plus script from a web server (URL) or the
    local file system (filename.ext) with specified parameters that
    will be assigned to substitution variables in the script.

When SQL*Plus starts, and after CONNECT commands, the site profile
(e.g. $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql) and the user profile
(e.g. login.sql in the working directory) are run.  The files may
contain SQL*Plus commands.

Refer to the SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference for more information.
[oracle@localhost ~]$ 
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus -l hr/oops

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Oct 13 12:19:42 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus hr/oops

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Oct 13 12:19:52 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name: hr
Enter password: 
Last Successful login time: Thu Oct 13 2022 10:23:49 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

Comment: `-l` works on Linux (at least - I thought it did on Windows too but rarely use it there).

Comment: my example is Oracle Linux